# Generating a table from fixed parameters

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to create a table like the following that will be used as X-axis for other Y-axis table data I have (also seven columns).

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 | Column 5 | Column 6 | Column 7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 17 | 33 | 49 | 65 | 81 | 97 |
| 2 | 18 | 34 | 50 | 66 | 82 | 98 |
| 3 | 19 | 35 | 51 | 67 | 83 | 99 |
| 4 | 20 | 36 | 52 | 68 | 84 | 100 |
| 5 | 21 | 37 | 53 | 69 | 85 | 101 |
| 6 | 22 | 38 | 54 | 70 | 86 | 102 |
| 7 | 23 | 39 | 55 | 71 | 87 | 103 |
| 8 | 24 | 40 | 56 | 72 | 88 | 104 |
| 9 | 25 | 41 | 57 | 73 | 89 | 105 |
| 10 | 26 | 42 | 58 | 74 | 90 | 106 |
| 11 | 27 | 43 | 59 | 75 | 91 | 107 |
| 12 | 28 | 44 | 60 | 76 | 92 | 108 |
| 13 | 29 | 45 | 61 | 77 | 93 | 109 |
| 14 | 30 | 46 | 62 | 78 | 94 | 110 |
| 15 | 31 | 47 | 63 | 79 | 95 | 111 |
| 16 | 32 | 48 | 64 | 80 | 96 | 112 |
| 113 | 129 | 145 | 161 | 177 | 193 | 209 |
| 114 | 130 | 146 | 162 | 178 | 194 | 210 |
| 115 | 131 | 147 | 163 | 179 | 195 | 211 |
| 116 | 132 | 148 | 164 | 180 | 196 | 212 |
| 117 | 133 | 149 | 165 | 181 | 197 | 213 |
| 118 | 134 | 150 | 166 | 182 | 198 | 214 |
| 119 | 135 | 151 | 167 | 183 | 199 | 215 |
| 120 | 136 | 152 | 168 | 184 | 200 | 216 |
| 121 | 137 | 153 | 169 | 185 | 201 | 217 |
| 122 | 138 | 154 | 170 | 186 | 202 | 218 |
| 123 | 139 | 155 | 171 | 187 | 203 | 219 |
| 124 | 140 | 156 | 172 | 188 | 204 | 220 |
| 125 | 141 | 157 | 173 | 189 | 205 | 221 |
| 126 | 142 | 158 | 174 | 190 | 206 | 222 |
| 127 | 143 | 159 | 175 | 191 | 207 | 223 |
| 128 | 144 | 160 | 176 | 192 | 208 | 224 |

So, as you can see the numbering start from 1, goes down 16 rows and then jump to column 2 with the value 17 and so on. Can I create a table in Power BI Desktop that generates this table from me based on the parameters I provide. The parameters will be mainly the window (in this case 16) ,the number of columns and rows. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following in PowerQuery:

```
let
    rows = 32, columns = 7, window = 16,
    Source = Table.FromList(List.Numbers(1, rows * columns), Splitter.SplitByNothing(), {"Value"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Column", each "Column " & Text.From( Number.RoundUp([Value] / window) - columns * Number.RoundDown(([Value]-1) / window / columns) ) ),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Row", each [Value] - (Number.RoundDown( ([Value] -1 ) / window) * window) + (Number.RoundUp([Value] / (window * columns) ) - 1) * window ),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom1", {{"Column", type text}}), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom1", {{"Column", type text}})[Column]), "Column", "Value")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```